# Mac App Store stuck with app update

Tags: mac-appstore, error

It's been like this for months:

[image]

A friend of mine downloaded Angry Birds on his account, then signed out. Then a week later I said "I'm never going to play this." and deleted the app, however, the update still remains.

Hitting update returns "Unknown Error".  Attempting to purchase Angry Birds again or re-sintall it on any account (even my friends) returns "Unknown Error", and then "The app store encountered a problem. Please try again later. (4)"

How can I get it to go away!? It won't display my *other* app updates either! My update tab is just broken and stuck on Angry Birds.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using AppZapper to remove App Store pref files. Works for a moment, then if you hit the updates tab it refreshes and goes back.
2. Re-installing Angry Birds
3. Changing accounts and trying the above.
4. Signing out of iTunes

Nothing works. Am I doomed to see that update forever?

Comment: The icon looks weird to me. Do you use some kind of mods?

Comment: It's a custom icon, yes. That's irrelevant.

Comment: @JacksonGariety did you fixed this error?

Comment: Got my friend to sign into his account, re-downloaded it, removed it.

Comment: @JacksonGariety redownloading it and then remove? hmm

Comment: @JacksonGariety If you fixed the problem, you should probably make an answer for it. That way, your question won't appear in Unanswered so others can easily find the answer.

Comment: @loldop Yes, it had already been deleted, that's why it was a problem in the first place.